# How to select the subset of data from each category using for loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have customer data (in CSV format) as:

```
index category  text
 0    spam      you win much money
 1    spam      you win 7000 car
 2    not_spam  the weather in Chicago is nice
 3    neutral   we have a party now
 4    neutral   they are driving to downtown
 5    not_spam  pizza is an Italian food
```

As an example, each category contains various count:

```
customer.category.value_counts():    

spam       100
not_spam   20
neutral    45
```

where:

```
min(customer.category.value_counts()): 20
```

I want to write a `for loop` in python to create a new data file that for all `category` only contains the same size equal to the smallest category count (in the example here smallest category is `not_spam`).

My expected output would be:

```
new_customer.category.value_counts():    

spam       20
not_spam   20
neutral    20
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to use `groupby`:

```py
min_count = df.category.value_counts().min()
df.groupby('category').head(min_count)
```

That said, if you really want a loop, you can use it as a list comprehension which is faster:

```py
categories = df.category.unique()
min_count = df.category.value_counts().min()
df = pd.concat([df.query('category==@cat')[:min_count] for cat in categories])
```

Comment: Note that you can replace `.head(min_count)` by `.sample(min_count)` to get random rows.

Answer (score 1):

My randomly generated dataframe has 38 rows with the following distribution of categories:

```
spam        17
not_spam    16
neutral      5
Name: category, dtype: int64
```

I was thinking that the first thing you need to do is to find the smallest category, and once you know that, you could [`.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) each category using calculated value as `n`:

```py
def sample(df: pd.DataFrame, category: pd.Series):
    threshold = df[category].value_counts().min()
    for cat in df[category].unique():
        data = df.loc[df[category].eq(cat)]
        yield data.sample(threshold)


data = sample(df, "category")
pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
    text    category
0   v   not_spam
1   l   not_spam
2   q   not_spam
3   j   not_spam
4   f   not_spam
5   l   spam
6   t   spam
7   r   spam
8   n   spam
9   k   spam
10  n   neutral
11  n   neutral
12  d   neutral
13  q   neutral
14  l   neutral
```

Comment: thanks for the comment and code. Can we add a random seed to make it better for reproducibilty?

Comment: @Bilgin sure thing. just add `random_state` arg to `sample()` like `data.sample(threshold, random_state=1)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work. it keeps concatenating generated top min records from each category

```
minval = min(df1.category.value_counts())
df2 = pd.concat([df1[df1.category == cat].head(minval) for cat in df1.category.unique() ])
print(df2)
```